# Socket communication crashes only on certain device with no visible reason, how to debug it?

Tags: android, sockets, debugging, client-server

I am experiencing this problem with a simple client server application.
Details:

- the server is running on a Raspberry Pi v2, a C++ application
- the client is the Android app, tested on two devices: a fast handset (HTC One M8 running Android 5.0.1) and a relatively slow tablet (Samsung Tab4 7" running 4.4.2)
- all communication is happening only over WiFi (Rpi is the hotspot)
- the communication is done using a simple protocol: the client sends a request and waits for the answer from the server
- all requests are working fine (out of 23 different ones) except the one I am experiencing the problem with
- the request is always a 8 byte header and optional parameters
- there is no parameter for this particular request
- the answer should be a 8 byte header and a 4 byte response payload for this request
- the request is sent every second
- the communication is handled on an AsyncTask

The bug:

The server reports that the answer was sent to the client, yet the client times out after 1.5 seconds (value chosen by me) like the data was lost. The weird part is that it only happens on the M8, the tablet never showed this bug. It happens every time after a certain amount of time, 1-5 minutes, it seems to be a systematic problem.

Can you please help me finding the root cause of the bug?

**EDIT:**
I recently discovered the Android Device Monitor -> Network Statistics which is clearly showing that something happened, but I'm not sure how to interpret this graph:

[image]

My code reports that the socket is timing out at 21:24:27.046. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a specific sequence of requests that are sent periodically? if yes, can you re-order it just to check if it will fail on the same request?

Comment: Usually there are a bunch of requests at the beginning (setup of the app), afterwards only this request is sent, it is a result polling of a long process running on the server. Reordering, I'm afraid, is not applicable here...

Comment: The root cause is still hidden but I managed to overcome it with a recovering mechanism: whenever my socket times out (doesn't happen too often) I am forcing the socket to close and reopen a new one with the same parameters. The user cannot notice it, so for now I'm fine with it.

Comment: Have you tried changing this timeout of 1.5 seconds to a larger value, to see if the timeout will not occur, and to a smaller value to see if the timeout will occur with some other requests as well?